# C# application will not display last Attribute Value in XML Document

Tags: c#, xml

A C# project I am working on will not display/insert the last value within an XML tag. 
For Example my application iterates through this tag and will get 1, 2 3 but not 4. It does that with every iteration.

```
<purpose>
 <intendedUse id="1"/>
 <intendedUse id="2"/>
 <intendedUse id="3"/>
 <intendedUse id="4"/>
</purpose>
```

I believe it has something to do with the `int num` declaration. NOTE: I commented my sqlite command so i wont write to the database. I have a messagebox to display what the values will be.

```
 for (i = 0; i < xmlnode.Count - 1; i++ )
            {
                str = xmlnode[i].Attributes[0].Value;
                int num = Int32.Parse(str) - 1;
                for ( var count = 0; count < xmlnode[num].FirstChild.NextSibling.ChildNodes.Count - 1; count++)
                {
                    str2 = xmlnode[num].FirstChild.NextSibling.ChildNodes[count].Attributes[0].Value; 
                    MessageBox.Show(str2);
                }

                //SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand(connection);
                //cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO languagePurpose (purposeID, languageID) VALUES ('" + str2 + "', '" + str + "')";
                //SQLiteDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
               // MessageBox.Show(str);
            }
```

Comment: Any reason you aren't using LinqToXML?

Comment: Its a project, to learn XML.

Comment: what's `xmlnode`? why do you need `xmlnode.Count - 1` in `i < xmlnode.Count - 1`? That is it looks like you deliberately skip the last node.

Comment: This has nothing to do with your question, but I can see in your commented out code that you're introducing variables directly into a SQL statement...NEVER DO THAT!  Use parameters in your sql instead. [Example in SQLite](http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/sqlite/docs/Devart.Data.SQLite~Devart.Data.SQLite.SQLiteCommand~Parameters.html)

Comment: @nadia {xmlnode} is an xmlnodelist within an xml tag.  xmlnode.count counts the nodes within a parent tag -1 since it starts at 0. I dont think that xmlnode.count is the problem because it displays all my attributes for my parent tag correctly. its the nested for loop that skips the last attibute within the nested tag set, which is xmlnode.

Comment: just try `i < xmlnode.Count` without -1, as it is you loop from 0 to 2( i<4-1 => i<3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. I was supposed to remove the `-1` in

```
count < xmlnode[num].FirstChild.NextSibling.ChildNodes.Count - 1`
```

Didnt notice until @Nadia brought it up for my first for loop, and I didn't notice that I added the `-1` by habit.

Answer (score 3):

This probably isn't the answer you are looking for, but in Linq-to-XML this is very easy.  Lets assume you loaded your xml into a `XDocument` named "xml".

```
for(XNode node in xml.Element("purpose").Elements("intendedUse"))
{
    //sets the value of the id attribute to str2
    str2 = node.Attribute("id").Value;
}
```

With the above solution you can have a possible `NullReferenceException` if the no id attribute exists, or there's no "purpose" nodes, but the concept should be pretty clear from my example.

Obviously you can do whatever you want in there, but LINQ-to-XML is far easier to use than `XmlDocument` especially if you're trying to learn how to do XML parsing.

Here's a link to get you started:  [Linq-to-XML MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx)